# Selecting the last line of a <p> element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am aware of the `:first-line` selector in CSS, but I cannot find anything that will allow me to select the last line.

The reason I am trying to select the last line is because I want to be able to define the `text-overflow` and `white-space` attributes of the last line.

I am trying to avoid using JavaScript to form a solution.

Comment: `text-overflow` by definition cannot operate on boxes that flow for more than one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this can be done with CSS alone.  jQuery or a PHP function might be able to get want you what

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately there is no CSS selector that would apply.

You can however select the first line using the pseudo element `:first-line`. Unfortunately at the moment there is no equivalent for the last line.

Answer (score 4):

IIRC, the only css control over the last line is text-align:

```
text-align-last: right;
```

I'm afraid javascript, or actually wrapping the last line in a span and styling that, is the only way. Below is the JS for reference.

```
var thetext = document.getElementById('some_element').innerHTML.split(/\r?\n/);
alert(thetext[thetext.length - 1]);
```

Comment: You can't split it that way. Browsers don't add newlines to an element's inner text or HTML wherever text wraps to the next line.

Comment: I second BoltClock's comment. That does not answer the problem.

Comment: Sorry, misinterpreted the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getComputedStyle` to attempt to "clone" the original paragraph styles.  Then set `height:auto` on the clone and add words in 1 by 1 detecting wrapping based on the `offsetHeight` change of the clone.

This probably doesn't work under a variety of conditions:

- when absolute positioning with top/right/bottom/left set
- when using auto-hyphenation to break words across lines
- when paragraph includes inline elements that change font size, weight, character spacing, etc.
- when `p { line-height:0; }`
- probably a lot more

But for simple cases, it does work if you really need it.  But it is definitely a hack.  You can use similar technique to figure out text size to avoid wrapping when working with dynamic text length (contrived example...usually not user friendly to dynamically size text).

[Pen](https://codepen.io/matp/pen/gOEwpEv) if the below example doesn't work or if you prefer pug/scss.

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/19824266/
function copyNodeStyle(sourceElement, targetElement) {
    var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(sourceElement);
    Array.from(computedStyle).forEach(function (key) {
        return targetElement.style.setProperty(key, computedStyle.getPropertyValue(key), computedStyle.getPropertyPriority(key));
    });
}

function getElementHeight(el) {
    return el.offsetHeight;
}

function createTestElement(sourceElement) {
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
        elTest = document.createElement(sourceElement.tagName);

    body.appendChild(elTest);
    copyNodeStyle(sourceElement, elTest);
    elTest.style.height = 'auto';  // so height adjusts based on content (width should be fixed to match original)
    elTest.style.transform = 'translateX(-2000px);'; // make sure test element is hidden out of viewport.  
    // could break things if original sizing was dependent on a transform

    elTest.textContent = 'A';  // default content, single character (no wrapping possible)

    return elTest;
}

function getLines(sourceElement) {
    var elTest = createTestElement(sourceElement),
        oneLineParagraphHeight = getElementHeight(elTest),
        tokens = sourceElement.textContent.split(/ +/g),
        lines = [],
        line = '', token, currHeight;

    for (token of tokens) {
        // add the next token and check if we wrapped
        elTest.textContent = line + ' ' + token;
        currHeight = getElementHeight(elTest);

        if (currHeight > oneLineParagraphHeight) { // adding this token caused wrap
            lines.push(line);
            line = token; // this token starts a new line
        }
        else {
            line += ' '+token;  // token part of current line
        }
    }
    lines.push(line);
    elTest.remove();  // remove our test element
    return lines;
}


const sourceElement = document.querySelector('#demo'),
      lines = getLines(sourceElement);

console.log('lines', lines);

// modify last line (so there was some point to getting lines)
lines[lines.length-1] = '<span class="last-line">'+lines[lines.length-1]+'</span>';
sourceElement.innerHTML = lines.join(' ');
```

```css
p#demo {
    width: 300px; /* constrain width so text wraps */
    border: 1px solid red; /* so we can see bounding box */
}

p#demo .last-line {
    color: purple;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec pellentesque lectus in pellentesque dictum. Maecenas ultrices et neque in iaculis. Maecenas accumsan leo vel dolor sollicitudin gravida.</p>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use only one line and give css : `nth-child(3)`

Here (3) denotes the number of a last line

Comment: Can you provide an example of this?

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: This is a misunderstanding of the nth-child selector.