# Advanced CSS challenge: underline only the final line of text with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to underline the final line of multi-line text, or at least create the allusion of it. Look closely at the following examples, because I'm trying to do something tricky.

**A.** Here's what I want to happen (the `__` marks the where the text should be underlined):

```
A line of text that is long enough so that it wraps
to another line.
________________
```

**B.** Here's what I DON'T want:

```
A line of text that is long enough so that it wraps
___________________________________________________
to another line.
________________
```

**C.** Or this:

```
A line of text that is long enough so that it wraps
to another line.
___________________________________________________
```

This effect is for a CMS so I won't know the precise length of text. This means that manually inserting `<span>`s or `<u>` tags are not an option. I also don't want to user javascript. I'm well aware that the effect I want is not the default behavior and that this will require some tricky CSS/HTML magic. But I feel like it might be possible. If you can't think of a way to do it, please don't bother to submitting an answer. Everything is impossible until you figure out how to do it.

Comment: What is the containing element?

Comment: Just like derekmx271 said, it's probably a `border-bottom` you want to apply to the surrounding `div`, rather than underlining the text.

Comment: @derekmx271 The containing element can be anything we want.

Comment: @NSAddict `border-bottom` will only achieve the 3rd effect in the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting the last line of a <p> element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227564/selecting-the-last-line-of-a-p-element)

Answer (score 19):

Here's a variation on what @albert was doing. It uses the `p:after{}` trick but with different `display`. The `<p>` seems to have to be `position:relative;` to work.

```
<style>
p{position:relative; display:inline}
p:after{position:absolute; left:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:1px; border-bottom:1px solid #000; content:""}
</style>
<p>first line of test text which is long enough to stretch onto a second line .</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VHdyf/

One cool thing about this approach is that it still uses `border-bottom`, which I prefer to using `underline` in most cases.

Comment: cool man. the p needs the position setting in order for the generated content to work. hope its what you need

Comment: I don't have access to a bunch of browsers to test this right now. I'm curious to know how cross-browser friendly this is, especially in IE7/8/9

Comment: pretty sure ie8 supports it. idk man, caniuse.com should know.

Comment: caniuse.com confirms `:after` should work in IE7+, which is great. But I know better than to get too excited before checking to make sure everything works together as expected. Especially the styling ON the :after content. IE has broken my heart too many times. ;-)

Comment: haha. right there with ya man. if it's not cross-browser than it's not a solution

Comment: Then why tag the question with HTML5 & CSS3 if the solution must work in IE7?

Comment: The question was to figure out if it was possible. I thought that CSS3 etc would be needed but it looks like I was wrong. The cross-browser issue simply speaks to whether or not one can actually use it for production work.

Comment: On Firefox, the jsfiddle shows a border under the *first* line of text.

Comment: This works great save for Firefox. Does anyone have a solution that works on all major modern browsers?

Comment: I had this issue and I just hid the ::after on Firefox. Here's what I added to my CSS:
`@supports (-moz-appearance:none) { 
 element::after {
  content: none;
 }
}
`

Answer (score 6):

```css
.title {
  width: 700px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.title:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 1px;
  box-shadow: -100vw 100vw 0 100vw;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
</h1>
```

Comment: That looks very promising! Can you explain how your solution works? Why does the underline match the width of the final line? What is `box-shadow` doing?

Comment: This looks a great solution. Is it cross browser friendly? How is this working? Why does has it not been voted as the solution?

Answer (score 5):

you can use css generated content to achieve the effect. i set up an example on jsfiddle, but essentially you add the border to `p:after{}`; in this example, the border stretches all the way across, which seems undesirable, however thats just because the parent container is vanilla for demos. i think it should be adaptable for your situation. here ya go: http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/bJ9D4/

Comment: I don't understand. You're saying your solution would work but it doesn't? This looks like **C** from above. I don't get it.

Comment: no it works. i was just being clear that a quick glimpse at it, without understanding what was going would make an easy assumption that it was not. also i don't see the difference you make between a and c. either way, it adds a border to the bottom of paragraphs

Comment: Look at the difference between the lengths of the underline. In **A** it matches the final line of text but in **C** it stretches the full width of the container, which appears to be the case in your example.

Comment: +1 for a very clever attempt. Check out the variation I submitted. I bet we can make it even better...

Comment: css generated content is slick. i used it whenever i can

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: Chances are that this is not possible, but please consider this answer to be thinking out loud / suggestion of a place to start looking, than than working code.*

Is there possibility of highlighting the lines of text (with a colour that matches the background colour) and then adjusting the line-height such that the background of the lower lines overlap the underline?

Pictures say a thousand words, so take a look at these:

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

From these mock-ups you can see that there are a couple of caveats and do not match exactly what is being asked for, but perhaps this is a starting point..?

Comment: I think it's a very interesting direction of thought. I was thinking about something similar, but couldn't figure out how to handle the "overhanging" underline from the top row. Maybe try a combination fo this approach with albert's `:after`?

Answer (score -1):

According to this:

[Selecting the last line of a <p> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227564/selecting-the-last-line-of-a-p-element)

it won't be possible unless you use some JavaScript..

Comment: My question specifically acknowledged that this is a challenge and requests that you not submit "can't do it" answers.

Comment: It is still the correct answer, though it is better to close the question as duplicate.

Comment: @Emerson I just told you that there is no official way of doing this in CSS, like you've seen this will cause trouble with browser compatibilities. I'm sorry but you'll either have to do it in Javascript or live with it.

Comment: I do not agree with Emerson's tone, but the answer you link to shows that you aren't able to select only the last line. To my mind, this does not exclude the possibility of this question being answered. (eg, consider selecting/altering every line except the last as opposed to selecting only the last line?)

Answer (score -1):

If this is the text "A line of text that is long enough so that it wraps to another line." and you want to underline "it wraps to another line." all you need is to use the selector.

For Html:

```
<div>
     A line of text that is long enough so that 
     <last>it wraps to another line.<last>
<div>
```

For CSS:

```
div last{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: `<last>` is not valid HTML. Also, OP noted "I won't know the precise length of text", so they wouldn't know where to put the tag with the underline style