# Restrict border width to text width in a block element

Tags: css, css-float, positioning

I have an `<h2>` title into a fixed with `<div>` (238px). When this page is rendered, the browser manage line breaks into the title to make the text fit the width (238px).

But the width property of the h2 element is still 238px, no matters where the line breaks are.

I want to set a `border-bottom` only under the text, and not under the full width of the h2 element, and I don't know how to achieve this using CSS.

You can see what I mean here : http://jsfiddle.net/np3rJ/2/

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are willing to use `display: table-cell`, and pseudo-elements, you can have a pretty good solution (with some minor limitations).

The HTML does not change:

```
<div class="dossier_titre">
    <h2>Horizon 2020, nouvelles opportunités</h2>
</div>
```

and you can apply the following CSS:

```
.zone_33 {
    width: 238px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.zone_33 .dossier_titre {
    margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
}

.zone_33 h2 {
    color: #616263;
    font-size: 150%;
    font-weight: lighter;
    padding: 0px 0px 12px 0px;
    background: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    display: table-cell;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.zone_33 .dossier_titre:after {
    content: "";
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}
```

For the `<h2>` element, set `display: table-cell`, and add a pseudo-element after `.dossier_titre` (the containing block for the header/title element).  The pseudo-element is also a `table-cell` and has a width of 100% (this is the key).

Also, since `h2` is no longer a block element, add your margins to `.dossier_titre` to maintain the visual spacing in our layout.

**How This Works**
I am creating a two-cell table with the second cell (the pseudo-element) having a width of 100%.  This triggers the browser to calculate the shrink-to-fit width for the first cell (`h2`) that contains the title text.  The first cell's width is thus the minimal needed to display the text. The bottom border is as long as the longest text line in the text block within the table-cell.

**Limitations**
`table-cell` is not supported in IE7 without a hack, but the work-around is fairly well known and can be found if needed.

If the title had many short words, you might get the line breaking in unexpected places.  You would need to insert `&nbsp` to keep specific words together as needed.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/h34pL/

Comment: plus one display-table cell for the way \o/

Answer (score 18):

I think this is what you need:

```html
<h2><span>Horizon 2020, nouvelles opportunités</span></h2>
```

```css
h2 span {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
h2 span::after{
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 1px; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000; 
    content: ""
}
```

#### [Working demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b8cwD/4/)

I used the technique described in this answer: [Advanced CSS challenge: underline only the final line of text with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180827/advanced-css-challenge-underline-only-the-final-line-of-text-with-css)

I introduced a `span` into the `H2` in order not to change the display attribute of it, but you could just as easily use the same technique with a `display: inline` on your H2. This method would allow the control of the actual line though rather than setting `display: inline` if needed

Comment: Doesn't work with Firefox (19.0.2) but works well on Chrome. Anyway, this is a nice state of the art solution.

Comment: Works on Firefox 57.0+ now, and is simpler than the chosen answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

This works on Chrome.

```
h2 {
   width: fit-content;
}
```

Comment: Best approach .

Comment: Thanks bro for the fix : )

Answer (score 15):

Maybe `display: inline-block;` Or `display: inline;` is what you need?

Comment: I second this answer. Change inline-block to inline, and remove bottom-padding (else your borders will be displaced).

Comment: This way I get the underline on every line of text, that's not what I need.

Answer (score 4):

Why not try:

```
text-decoration:underline
```

?

EDIT

Just make a span around "OPPORTUNITÉS" with the underline.

```
 <h2>Horizon 2020, nouvelles <span class="underline">opportunités</span> </h2>
.underline {
    text-decoration:underline
}
```

Comment: I want the border only under the text block, not under each line.

Comment: This is a smart solution and easy to implement.

Comment: I used the span idea from @Santiago to apply a border-bottom to the element. That way I could give it a color and thicker weight and still only apply the underline to the width of the text and not the block level menu item. 

 li:hover > a span {
  border-bottom: 2px solid green;
  }

Answer (score 2):

Can try "text-underline-position" property instead of table-cell and border. Make it simple!

```
text-decoration: underline;
text-underline-position: under;
```

Answer (score 1):

All you can do is put your h2 element text into span like this:

```
<h2><span>Horizon 2020, nouvelles opportunités</span></h2>
```

and in css remove border-bottom from `.zone_33 h2 {}` and put it like this:

```
.zone_33 h2 span{ border-bottom: 1px solid grey;}
```

by this border-bottom will come under full text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, (I think it will help you)

```
.heading {
    position: relative;
    color: $gray-light;
    font-weight: 700;
    bottom: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.heading::after {
    position: absolute;
    display:inline-block;
    border: 1px solid $brand-primary !important;
    bottom: -1px;
    content: "";
    height: 2px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could put a border-bottom and change the width of your h2 so that the border length matches your h2 length. Adjust the width to the width of your h2, taking into consideration it's font-size. Then add a padding-bottom to your h2 and set it to your liking.

```
    <h2>Cats</h2>
    h2{
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width: 64px;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please provide a code snippet to explain your answer?