# Underline only final line of text when centered

Tags: html, css, layout

I want to underline only the last line of some text. When the text wraps to more rows, still only the last line has to be underlined.

I found this [Solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180827/advanced-css-challenge-underline-only-the-final-line-of-text-with-css). But that does not work when the text is centered. Because the line stretches all the way to the left on the last row when the text gets wrapped.

```css
p{
  position: relative;
  display: inline
}
p:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -15px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #000;
  content: ""
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <p>Een lijn onder alleen de laatste regel, werkt ook op mobiel als de tekst over meerdere regels valt</p>
</div>
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VHdyf/69/)

Anyone has an idea?

Thx!

Comment: I tried playing with some code with no success. Could you be happy with a reduced width border at the bottom that is independent of the width of the last line?

Answer (score 3):

I guess that's what OP wants:

```css
.underlined {
  position: relative;
}

.text {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.line {
  color: transparent;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
}

.line:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<p class="underlined">

  <span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui sed ratione voluptatum ducimus unde velit debitis asperiores expedita, a deleniti repellat quis officia. Voluptate, earum rerum itaque, iste eligendi velit!</span>

  <span class="line">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui sed ratione voluptatum ducimus unde velit debitis asperiores expedita, a deleniti repellat quis officia. Voluptate, earum rerum itaque, iste eligendi velit!</span>

</p>
```

I don't like this solution because it requires to duplicate the content, but maybe someone has an idea to improve it...

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jordinebot/shzn7xd4/)

---

**Edit:** Adding a screenshot of my result:

[image: Chrome Screenshot]

**Is doesn't work in Firefox 50.0**

Comment: That is full width too. No different to just having a border.

Comment: Just checked. Chrome is OK

Comment: Thx, Jordi,  but like R Reveley says, it does not work in Firefox

Answer (score 1):

I answered similar question. 
It can't be done in pure css.
I have created the fiddle using javascript.
http://jsfiddle.net/VHdyf/89/

Javascript part

```
var parentEl = document.getElementsByClassName('customBtn');

for(var i=0;i<parentEl.length;i++){
var currentEl = parentEl[i];
var button = currentEl.childNodes[1];
var words = button.innerText.split(/[\s]+/); // An array of allthe words split by spaces, since that's where text breaks by default. var
var lastLine = []; // Putall words that don't change the height here.
var currentHeight = currentEl.clientHeight; // The starting height.
while(1){
  lastLine.push(words.pop());
  button.innerText = words.join(' ');
  if (currentEl.clientHeight < currentHeight) {
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.classList=['underline'];
    span.innerText = ' '+lastLine.reverse().join(' ');
    button.appendChild(span);
    break;
  }
  currentHeight = parentEl[i].clientHeight;
  if(!words.length){
    break;
  }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following CSS

```
div > p:last-child:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -15px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #000;
    content: ""
}
```

Here is updated [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VHdyf/66/)

Comment: Thank you,  but it does not work. The line stretches to the far left of the div, even is the bottom line is shorter then the line above.

Comment: check the JSfiddle above in answer, its working there

Comment: Thank you for quick reply, but not working.  The line is longer than the last words of the text.  It has to be only under the last words

Comment: Can you explain more or update your JS Fiddle but the exact problem you're having?

Comment: I have updated:  http://jsfiddle.net/VHdyf/69/    When you make the screen smaller,  you see the text gets wrapped, and the line starts at the far left of the div, not only under the last words.

Comment: Thank you,  but now the line has the full width of the div.  I want the line only under the words in the bottom line.

Comment: Paragraph tag has display:inline-block that will not make it full width, view the JSfiddle in full width, its just covering the width of P tag

Comment: Ah i see,  but i still al looking for a solution to underline only the bottom words.

Comment: you can easily do it if you assign span tag to the last line