# CSS/Javascript Challenge - Want to implement border bottom only for last line with centered text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to implement this layout for buttons on a project.

[image: Button mockup]

Things I have tried.

Recommendations from this [Advanced CSS challenge: underline only the final line of text with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180827/advanced-css-challenge-underline-only-the-final-line-of-text-with-css)
but it only works for left aligned texts while I want to implement a text-align centered button.

The above post suggests:

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline
}

a:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  content: ""
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Lorem Ipsum Foo Bar</a>
```

Fiddle Try http://jsfiddle.net/VHdyf/88/

[Underline only final line of text when centered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40759885/underline-only-finel-line-of-text-when-centered) This post is still open and suggests on duplicate content for this.
Any other ideas required.

This is meant to be responsive, so can't use a `span` inside just for the last line and give it a border.

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Underline only finel line of text when centered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40759885/underline-only-finel-line-of-text-when-centered)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript for this. This way you can use apply any CSS to your links and don't have to worry about it.

JavaScript algorithm of finding and highlighting words of last line:

1. Iterate through all links. Skip this step if you need to apply this style to only one element.
2. Get element's text (`innerText`).
3. Split text by whitespace (" ") sign.
4. Remove all elements from block.
5. Add `span`s with words and `span`s with whitespace (also save this `span`s to array).
6. Sort this array by `span` with the hightest `top` lowest `left` of `span`'s rectangle to get first word of last line.
7. Get top element of this array.
8. Add highlighting class to the this element and its next siblings.

```js
highlightLastLineForLinks();

// apply highlighting on window resize
window.addEventListener("resize", highlightLastLineForLinks);


// utility method to find all siblings
function getNextSiblings(elem, filter) {
  var sibs = [];
  while (elem = elem.nextSibling) {
    if (!filter || filter(elem)) sibs.push(elem);
  }
  return sibs;
}

function highlightLastLineForLinks() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll("a");

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    highlightLastLine(elements[i]);
  }
}

// Peforms highlighting for single element
function highlightLastLine(element) {
  var text = element.innerText.trim();

  // get words list
  var words = text.split(" ");

  // removing all elements
  while (element.firstChild) {
    element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
  }

  var spanArray = [];

  // add spans with words and whitespaces
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    // append span with word */
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(words[i]));
    element.appendChild(span);
    // save span element to array
    spanArray.push(span);

    span = document.createElement("span");
    // append whitespace
    span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" "));
    element.appendChild(span);
    // save span element to array
    spanArray.push(span);
  }

  // sorting by highest top and lowest left
  spanArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    var rectA = a.getBoundingClientRect();
    var rectB = b.getBoundingClientRect();

    var deltaTop = rectB.top - rectA.top;

    // if differense is less then 1px
    if (Math.abs(deltaTop) < 1) {
      return rectA.left - rectB.left;
    }

    return deltaTop;
  });

  // appending highlighting to siblings of first word of last line
  var lastLineSpans = getNextSiblings(spanArray[0]);
  // also include the same element
  lastLineSpans.unshift(spanArray[0]);

  for (var i = 0; i < lastLineSpans.length; i++) {
    var lastLineSpan = lastLineSpans[i];
    lastLineSpan.classList.add("underline");
  }
}
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;

  /* just styles for demo */
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.underline {
  border-bottom: 1px solid currentColor;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>

<a href="#">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis venenatis purus non elit imperdiet, non dictum turpis pharetra. Duis a posuere neque, quis pellentesque urna. In id massa mollis, consectetur velit id, fermentum ipsum. Maecenas vehicula leo sit amet massa volutpat consectetur. Cras eu varius justo. Donec ultrices eu est et mattis. Praesent mollis varius ultrices. Pellentesque tempus mauris diam, id scelerisque sem sollicitudin eu. Cras lacinia volutpat sapien ut pellentesque. Pellentesque sollicitudin eleifend sodales. Nulla ornare ex tellus, eget fermentum diam facilisis in.
</a>

<a href="#">
Phasellus nec malesuada tortor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis commodo quam at lectus feugiat lacinia. Proin cursus vulputate hendrerit. Duis sit amet fringilla dui. Sed euismod viverra tellus id viverra. Morbi ultrices nulla sed libero porttitor, nec sollicitudin risus blandit. Nulla maximus purus id imperdiet tincidunt. Donec arcu velit, condimentum in euismod vitae, porta eget nibh. Sed auctor metus nulla, in pulvinar neque sodales in. Ut sodales eget diam non vehicula. Praesent ut convallis erat, et ultricies elit. Suspendisse vitae efficitur turpis, at accumsan nulla. Nullam vehicula, lorem quis fermentum tincidunt, enim mi tincidunt odio, nec rutrum est diam sed ipsum.
</a>

<a href="#">
Vivamus eleifend tincidunt urna. Mauris tellus turpis, malesuada nec venenatis nec, mollis et lorem. Nunc pharetra sapien quis justo lobortis molestie. Mauris facilisis ultricies mi, ut auctor lorem porta ac. Integer placerat gravida mi, a elementum nibh congue convallis. Phasellus posuere, mauris sit amet tempus venenatis, metus mi dignissim arcu, nec elementum enim libero ut leo. Aliquam nec est sapien. Mauris in suscipit risus, in lacinia nunc. Morbi at augue ligula. Duis eros quam, tincidunt et sollicitudin a, porta nec dolor. Sed consequat urna non purus ultricies, eget ullamcorper ante convallis.
</a>

<a href="#">
Vestibulum sit amet ante nec lectus dictum sodales ut sed nulla. Phasellus quis orci semper, fringilla neque ac, suscipit ex. Maecenas in sem nec odio sollicitudin imperdiet vitae in felis. Integer euismod eget justo sit amet finibus. Donec venenatis odio quis felis hendrerit posuere vel nec nisi. Ut facilisis commodo massa ac maximus. Suspendisse semper mattis aliquet. Phasellus tempus augue ligula, a pretium eros blandit a. Nullam sed nisi id nisi pharetra facilisis. Curabitur eu nisl mauris. Curabitur iaculis congue augue, vel convallis purus mollis et. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam tempor arcu vel molestie eleifend.
</a>

<a href="#">
Quisque tincidunt non ex consectetur dapibus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vestibulum ultricies a nibh finibus vehicula. Suspendisse eu magna sed tortor sollicitudin porttitor. Quisque non turpis at diam eleifend elementum nec ac odio. Duis posuere dignissim risus, non semper arcu lacinia et. Cras mauris nulla, aliquam a maximus a, pellentesque eu est. Suspendisse sit amet laoreet risus. Nulla vestibulum vehicula metus, finibus porttitor ipsum fermentum eu.
</a>

<a href="#">
In at volutpat nibh. Vestibulum sit amet aliquet nisl. In iaculis lectus ac ligula molestie vestibulum. Quisque bibendum tempor luctus. Mauris fermentum blandit magna a malesuada. Donec sagittis odio tortor, non scelerisque odio scelerisque non. Donec tristique mi id lacus finibus vestibulum. Suspendisse convallis nunc facilisis, tempor lorem vitae, ultricies dolor. Nullam magna mauris, maximus vitae arcu ac, feugiat sodales nunc. Praesent ullamcorper, arcu sed elementum varius, mi lorem dapibus mauris, id ullamcorper odio ligula eu lacus. Nullam in porttitor sem. Donec vitae velit a leo mollis facilisis non in odio. Nam in auctor sapien, imperdiet mattis leo. Etiam at odio orci. Nunc at blandit eros. Cras semper non nulla et interdum.
</a>
```

You can also see how it works with window resizing via [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tw7p0uyk/).

Comment: Hey @Vadim,

Thanks, 
This is exactly what I was looking for.

What do you suggest, performance wise will it be ok to use this in production?

Comment: @AshishTewari Well, this should be really fluent. Nowadays browsers are very good at performing JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
a{position:relative; display:inline;text-align:center;}
a:after{position:absolute; left:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:1px; border-bottom:1px solid #000; content:""}
```

Put text-align : center on a (link) tag.

Comment: Hey Abhay,
This does not work

Check the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/VHdyf/88/
I tried using anchor tag as container and span inside to center and the result is not something i am looking for.

Comment: Hi Ashish, it can't be done in pure css.
I have implemented the solution using javascript.
Here's the fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/VHdyf/89/
I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Hey @Abhay,
Thanks, this does work, but I need my buttons to be responsive therefore giving fixed width won't work.

Comment: Just remove the width from css. It would work then also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on anchor tag

> text-align:center